# Save value outside loop in C

Tags: c, loops

I need to be able to use the value res defined inside the loop in the next loop but it doesn't seem to remember the value of res and defaults it back to 0 after the loops done

```
  do {
    if (binRep[i] == 1) {
      binRep[i + 1] = 1;
      res = i;
    }
    i--;
  }
  while (binRep[i] != 1);

  for (i = res; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (binRep[i] == 1)
      binRep[i] = 0;
    if (binRep[i] == 0)
      binRep[i] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: `res` is not defined in the loop.

Comment: Where is `res` even defined? Please include a [mre]

Comment: By the way `if(binRep[i] == 1) binRep[i] = 0; if(BinRep[i] == 0) binRep[i] = 1;` <- if the first branch is true then the second branch is also entered and `binRep[i]` goes back to `1`. I think you actually want `binRep[i] = !binRep[i];`

Comment: Note: the preceding comments may not make much sense if by "defined inside the loop" you are talking about a value being *assigned* to `res`.  That's not a definition in C terminology.  A definition would be a declaration of that variable, though not all declarations are also definitions.

Comment: If you want to find the first `binRep[i] == 1` encountered, you need a `break` after `res = i;`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific with your question?
You said you've defined `res` inside a loop but it seems to have been defined outside the loop.
If the variable `res` is defined outside `do_while` loop the changes made to the value of `res` should have been retained.
If you are defining a variable inside a loop its value will not get reflected outside that loop or in general outside its scope.